# Post Data PHP array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, curl, postdata

I assume this question is due to my lack of understanding of arrays in PHP.

Generally I am trying to send a post request in php using curl, however I want the postbody to look something like this:

```
{
   "deliveryAddress":[
      {
         "ID":"5",
         "address":"example@example2.com",
         "method":"EMAIL",
         "checkbox":true,
         "flashlight":false
      },
      {
         "ID":"7",
         "address":"example45@example3.com",
         "method":"EMAIL",
         "checkbox":true,
         "flashlight":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Is roughly what it looks like in the API, so if I drop this into a program like Fiddler it works perfectly fine. However turning that into the postbody in PHP I have more difficulty. Here is my best attempt so far:

```
$postData = array(
    'deliveryAddress' => array(
    'ID'=>  '5',
    'address'=>  'example@example2.com',
    'method'=>  'EMAIL',
    'checkbox'=>  true,
    'flashlight'=>  false,

    'ID'=>  '7',
    'address'=>  'example45@example3.com',
    'method'=>  'EMAIL',
    'checkbox'=>  true,
    'flashlight'=>  false,



    )

);

$url = "ServerIamSendingItTo";
$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(

    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: BASIC (mybase64encodedpass)=='
);





curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);



$result = curl_exec($ch);

$ch_error = curl_error($ch);

if ($ch_error) {

   echo"ERROR";
   curl_close($ch);

} else {


     var_dump($result);

}
curl_close($ch);
```

Clearly I am doing the postdata wrong, but I am not sure how to structure this. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: you want json, so use json_encode function

Comment: @moped I am using the json_encode function. 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeliveryAddress` is an array of objects (once JSON encoded)

So if you want to post data according to the JSON you wrote as example then the PHP array has to be built this way:

```
$postData = array(
    'deliveryAddress' => array(

        array (
            'ID'=>  '5',
            'address'=>  'example@example2.com',
            'method'=>  'EMAIL',
            'checkbox'=>  true,
            'flashlight'=>  false
            ),

        array (
            'ID'=>  '7',
            'address'=>  'example45@example3.com',
            'method'=>  'EMAIL',
            'checkbox'=>  true,
            'flashlight'=>  false
        )

    )
);
```

Note that on the "PHP side" `deliveryAddress` is now an array of associative arrays (that once `json_encoded` will turn in an array of objects).

Comment: So I assume after this I need to do something like $postData = json_encode($postData); ? Since right now I get a  unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting '('  (pointing to the line either at delivery address or right after it)

Comment: @Lain you are already encoding `$postData` when you pass the array to **curl**: in your code you have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));`

Comment: You are right, my mistake. But it does still give me the unexpected => error that I mentioned in that comment. It points to the line right above the first ID. that just says array =>( This is the right syntax? Since the other arrays you do : Array( instead of array => (

Comment: @Lain, sorry. There was a typo in the code in my answer! I fixed it just now